# Controller Action not called via Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got a controller action:

```
def delete_image
@pictureup = Pictureup.find(params[:id])

@pictureup.remove_image!

respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to root_url, notice: "Bild wurde gelöscht." }
  format.json { head :no_content }
end
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    redirect_to root_url, notice: "Bild gelöscht."
end
```

A route:

```
  match "delete_image/:id" => "pictureups#delete_image", :as => 'delete_img'
```

And a working generated Link, as long as i click myself on it:

```
<a href="/delete_image/157931" data-confirm="Are you sure?" id="alert">Delete</a>
```

If i try to do a

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
 jQuery('#alert').click();
});
```

The data-confirm dialog is displayed, but the controller action is not invoked (no redirect, no "image_delete")

Any ideas why? If i try it with one of the CRUD Actions in my controller its working without a problem.

Comment: Did you try calling `jQuery('#alert').click();` in the browser JS console?

Comment: Yep, nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

The `:confirm` in you link_to puts the `data-confirm` in the link when the page is rendered.  That causes Rail's jQuery-ujs stuff to bind a Javascript [confirm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.confirm) to the link.  If you check the jQuery-ujs source, you'll see that if the `confirm` is successful, a hidden form is submitted to the URL in the link_to.

So, the easiest thing for you to do is to remove the `:confirm` and do it all in jQuery yourself.  For regular "clicking on the link', you can bind your own `confirm` to the `click` and call another function if the confirm is successful.  If you want to just have the delete happen using jQuery, just call that second function directly.

Answer (score 0):

Ok got it fixed.

Changed the route:

```
  resources :pictureups do
   member do
    delete :delete_image
   end
  end
```

Changed the view:

```
<%= link_to "Delete", delete_image_pictureup_path(@pictureup), method: :delete, :id=>"delete_img" %>
```

And the JS:

```
jQuery('#delete_img').click();
```

So it seems to have something to do with the routing and calling verbs.